# Why can't I close this question as a duplicate?

Tags: bug, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

I was just trying to close [Why did Boeing use customer codes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82187/why-did-boeing-use-customer-codes) as a duplicate of [What use was there for Boeing to include customer numbers in their aircraft model names, and why did they end this practice?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82182/what-use-was-there-for-boeing-to-include-customer-numbers-in-their-aircraft-mode), but the system does not allow it:

[image: Error Message]

The error message does not make sense to me, since the linked question currently has 4 upvotes (although no accepted answer). **Why can't I close this?** Is this a bug?

Comment: Here is some information on Meta Stack Exchange: [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/295232)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can't read!** The error message says

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

and I misread that as

> This question does not have an **upvote** or an accepted answer

The question linked as the duplicate *must have an answer*, as explained on Meta: [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) (thanks to Glorfindel for the link), except when closed by a mod or when both questions are from the same user.